# How to log console errors to a file from reactjs application to a file using window.onerror?

Tags: reactjs

i am planning to log all the console errors from my reactjs application to file using window.onerror.

Could someone provide tutorial links to do for the whole application or some links that could help me start handling the errors from the frontend...

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--what kind of errors? Exceptions will already be logged.

Comment: Please paste what you have tried so far, we cannot help you without your code in the question.

Comment: @Dave Newton: javascript errors...thanks.

Comment: ... All errors will be JavaScript errors. Please be more specific.

Comment: all client side errors that occur in the application...i have a requirement to use window.onerror to do so...i am a newbie with this. and have no idea where and how to use this.

Comment: Set an `onerror` handler, but it's not clear what you aim to achieve--all JS error will already be run through the default handler, which logs to the console. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: thanks. i want to log those errors to a file instead of showing those errors in the console. i think for each component i have to set onerror event listener within componentDidMount?